# call php function name from a string

Tags: php

i created a php function to return or save some jsons, and the class looks like this.

```
<?php
    class calendarModel {

        // global variables
        var $user;
        var $action;
        var $connect;

        // init class
        function __construct($action = "getEvents") {
            $this->user = 1;

            $this->action = $action;

            $dbhost = "localhost";
            $dbport = "5432";
            $dbname = "fixevents";
            $dbuser = "postgres";
            $dbpass = "123";
            $this->connect = pg_connect("host=" . $dbhost . " port=" . $dbport . " dbname=" . $dbname . " user=" . $dbuser . " password=" . $dbpass);

            $this->executeAction();
        }

        // action router
        function executeAction() {
            if($this->action == "getEvents")
                $this->getEvents();
            else if($this->action == "moveEvent")
                $this->moveEvent();
            else if($this->action == "insertEvent")
                $this->insertEvent();
            else if($this->action == "updateEvent")
                $this->updateEvent();
            else if($this->action == "getCalendars")
                $this->getCalendars();
            else if($this->action == "toggleCalendar")
                $this->toggleCalendar();
            else if($this->action == "deleteCalendar")
                $this->deleteCalendar();
            else if($this->action == "insertCalendar")
                $this->insertCalendar();
        }

        // getEvents
        function getEvents() {
            //...
        }

        // moveEvent
        function moveEvent() {
            //...
        }

        // insertEvent
        function insertEvent() {
            //...
        }

        // updateEvent
        function updateEvent() {
            //...
        }

        // toggleCalendar
        function toggleCalendar() {
            //...
        }

        // deleteCalendar
        function deleteCalendar() {
            //...
        }

        // insertCalendar
        function insertCalendar() {
            //...
        }

    }

    // call class
    if(isset($_GET['action']))
        $instance = new calendarModel($_GET['action']);
    else
        $instance = new calendarModel();
?>
```

What i was wondering is, can i somehow call the action in the contruct from the string name instead make that big if / else if function called `executeAction`. Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: @zerkms `$this` will complicate things though.

Comment: @kapa: `call_user_func(array($this, 'methodname'))`

Comment: @zerkms Hm, haven't used PHP for some time. I thought you can only pass strings in the array. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: i tried call_user_func($action); and $action(); but they dont work

Comment: @Pacuraru Daniel: you probably read function documentation before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barmar is almost correct:
$this->{$action}();

Comment: thank you very much for this, this works perfect, i dont even need to make the execute Action function anymore, i just called it like this inside the contruct

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve to be checked, sorry

Comment: `$action` is a class property, you need `$this->`

Comment: actually i just used it exactly like this and it works for me, maybe it is because i am using it into the contructor

Comment: ops, it was a lack of attention of my part :/
Barmar is correct :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use an expression where the function name will be used, the value of the expression will be used as the function name:

```
function executeAction() {
    $this->{$this->action}();
}
```

Since you're getting the action from user input, make sure you validate it. Otherwise, someone could send input that makes you execute an arbitrary method.

Comment: thank you very much this works as intended :D i wish i could give you guys both correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that:

```
function __construct($action = "getEvents")
{
    ...
    $this->$action();
}
```

As $action is defined by the user, you might want to check whether $action is an existing function in your class:

```
if (array_key_exists($action, get_class_methods($this))) {
    $this->$action();
}
```